# Auth0 How to get user from jwt access token?

Tags: node.js, auth0

I well defined an API using Auth0 API jwt

```
app.post('/api/v1/subcorner', checkJwt, (req, res) => {
  console.log('POST /api/v1/subcorner :');
  console.log('Body :' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  console.log('Header :' + JSON.stringify(req.headers));

  const subcorner = req.body.subcorner_name;
  const description = "TBD";
  const creator = "Toto";

  check_subcorner();
  check_user();
  
  const subcorner_data = { name: subcorner, desc: description, creator: creator, timestamp: Date.now(), subscribers: [ creator ], moderators: [ creator ] };
  const data = JSON.stringify(subcorner_data);
  console.log("new subcorner: " + data);
  client.RPUSH("subcorners", data);

  res.json({ status: "OK" });
 });
```

The call pass through the checkJwt as expected, which is great. But now to get the creator, I would like to know the user id with the token. How can I do that? I dont want the api caller to put the user id in the body (because he can put anything) I want to be sure that the user Id is the one used to get the jwt token. How can I do that?

I tried to find in Auth0 doc how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Auth0's **Action** to solve your problem, here is the doc for Auth0's **Action**: https://auth0.com/docs/customize/actions/actions-overview, https://auth0.com/docs/customize/actions/write-your-first-action#create-an-action

an example for action:

```
exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
  const namespace = '' //namespace;
  api.idToken.setCustomClaim(namespace + 'user_id', event.user.user_id);
};
```

then decode in your `/api/v1/subcorner`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added the action like you mentioned. It was easy to do and deploy. but now on api side how can I decode it?